# Redirect SNMP ports to router for use with openHAB SNMP binding

Tags: raspbian, trap, snmp

OpenHAB provides an interesting SNMP binding that would allow me (I think) to get network bandwidth use statistics that may be used in rules.
Interesting as the may be, it seems that openHAB cannot connect to privileged ports, and will not run under sudo.

On my Raspberry Pi Rasbian box, I tried redirecting the ports to not privileged ones like this:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 2048 -j DNAT --to 10.0.1.1:161
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -d 10.0.1.1 -p tcp --dport 161 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 2049 -j DNAT --to 10.0.1.1:162
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -d 10.0.1.1 -p tcp --dport 162 -j ACCEPT
sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

where 10.0.1.47 is my raspberry pi and 10.0.1.1 is the router I want to monitor. This does not work, however, when trying to connect to 2049 (which should now be 162, which is SNMP TRAP).

Any ideas on what could be wrong here?

Fredrik

Comment: albeit SNMP is defined as both TCP and UDP, it is normally  a UDP   service for starters. 2049 is the NFS port also, I would user higher ports. I think the forward rules are not necessary as they are for routing.

Comment: I think you're chasing the wrong thing here.  OpenHAB shouldn't need to bind to privileged ports.  It should just grab some non-privileged ports on your pi and use those to connect to the SNMP ports on your router.  I would start by chasing that rabbit.